# difference between `wildignore=` and `wildignore+=` in vim

Tags: vimscript

I have seen **many vimrc's** which have `wildignore+=` and i don't know what it refers 
compared to `wildignore=`

others like: `clipboard=` and `clipboard+=`
some configs have also like `clipboard-=`

Can anyone tell me the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h :set+=`

```
:se[t] {option}+={value}                *:set+=*
            Add the {value} to a number option, or append the
            {value} to a string option.  When the option is a
            comma separated list, a comma is added, unless the
            value was empty.
            If the option is a list of flags, superfluous flags
            are removed.  When adding a flag that was already
            present the option value doesn't change.
            Also see |:set-args| above.
```

If you have default empty `wildignore` then:

1. `:set wildignore=*.o,*.obj` will set it to the `*.o,*.obj` value
2. `:set wildignore+=*.exe` will set it to the `*.o,*.obj,*.exe` value